# How do I grab IDL path for Microsoft Store apps?

Tags: windows, links, windows-store-app

Somewhere I found out that I can execute Serif Affinity apps via "**IDL: scheme links**". How can I get the same type of (IDL) links for other apps that I've installed via Windows Store, assuming they all have such IDL links, which I'm also curious to know?

I'm on Windows 11 Pro (v10.0.22621)

Affinity Photo:

```
IDL:?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
```

Affinity Designer:

```
IDL:?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
```

Affinity Publisher:

```
IDL:?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
```

Comment: You heard somewhere? Where? Did that source give info on how to get these? IDL can mean a couple different things: Interface Design Language or Interactive Data Language. Can you give more context? Also, what is it that you are trying to accomplish? Like, taking a few steps backwards, what is the problem you are actually trying to solve that led you to find IDL Scheme Links and this possible solution you're asking about? Understanding what you actually want may help us present a better answer overall.

Comment: @music2myear Alas, I can't find the source where I found these IDLs, might've been Affinity forum. I realize it's related to Interface Design Language whatever that is. It was never explained how they got these links.

The huge problem I want to solve is that Windows Store app exe's are only to be found in versioned folders. Which is terrible for programmatic links. If not for that: in some cases the exes are nowhere to be found/accessed and then you can't open files with these programs programmatically (I'm a AutoHotkey user). This is where knowing how to retrieve IDL links would be golden.

Comment: Yea, sounds like you should take a few steps backwards from where you think the solution is right now, and begin looking for solutions to the original problem. Edit your question, even substantially, that's fine and encouraged! Tell us what your original problem is that you're trying to solve, the one that got you to IDLs and all that. It sounds like you're trying to interact programmatically with Store applications. Dealing with programming may make this a better fit on StackOverflow, but lets start here.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear. In a nutshell I wanted to know how to get an IDL path to a Microsoft Store app.

Comment: This is not an URI scheme I ever heard of. You should take a step back and check what's handling these on your PC. Then it's possible to determine what you have here. Because these are not necessarily universal app links.

Comment: Fair point. I should've mentioned I use these URIs in Directory Opus and the source must've originated from their forum, although I couldn't find the exact page where I found these Affinity IDL URIs... Anyway, I asked the same question on the DOpus forum and they mention you might retrieve IDL paths for Store apps by dragging their icon from Start Menu to an editable toolbar (didn't work for me) eg. the one in DOpus that lets you add custom buttons including scripts/links etc: https://resource.dopus.com/t/what-are-idl-paths-and-how-do-i-retrieve-them-in-order-to-open-windows-store-apps/46428/1

Comment: Now that I’m back at my PC, I checked: Windows does _not_ do `idl:`. So it must be something you have installed. Go to “Choose default apps by protocol” and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this was a universal URI scheme (see example paths in question post) but as far as I can tell these paths do exist in the WIndows app Directory Opus, as a method for linking to Microsoft Store apps which are known for being tricky to make static links for.

Whether the use of IDL paths are strictly isolated to Directory Opus or not, I'm still not hundred percent sure, but I'll mark this question as answered for now, as there's a chance of this being an application-related question. I'll refer to the discussion on the Directory Opus forum [here](https://resource.dopus.com/t/what-are-idl-paths-and-how-do-i-retrieve-them-in-order-to-open-windows-store-apps/46428/2).